# Searching middle part of the string using Full Text Search in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not able to search the middle part of string using fulltext search index for eg:there was a string "I like music" i was not able to search for like which is in the middle part of string..

Answer (score 1):

Try [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) operator.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    YourTABLE 
WHERE 
    ColumnName LIKE '%like%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like` keyword in query as follows:

```
select * from tablename where col like '%like%'
```

Here is the tutorial of like in sql:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Here is the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to still use the fulltext index and to avoid a table scan, try this

```
 select * 
   from yourTable
  where contains (ColumnName,'like')
    and (ColumnName not like 'like%' or ColumnName like '_%like%')
```

However, the query optimizer might decide that a full table scan is more effective.

Comment: select * from eg_fulltext where contains (description,'"like"') and (description not like 'like%' or description like '_%like%')---It's not working

Comment: Hmm. I tested it and it does work on my machine. The second line filters out any lines with only one 'like' in the beginning of the sentence, whereas the first line only includes lines having a 'like' in a sentence. Can you describe, what is not working?

Comment: consider the table with having strings writes the task,reads the task,studies the task carefully i am searching for the word "the" for this word "the"  its not working for all other words it's working fine...

Comment: 'the' is a stop word. It is not included in the fulltext index by default. You have to disable using a stoplist. Try  `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON <Table> SET STOPLIST = OFF`. Your problem has got nothing to do with my proposal. It is a general fulltext issue (well, call it a feature)

Answer (score 0):

Check if statistics of your table out of date, especially check the statistics relates to your fulltext index. Since you are using SQl Server 2008, so,  you can query DMV to get statistics information of your index or using DBCC to see the statistics detail information

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("[schema].[table]",indexname);
```

Check the first return result, [Updated], [rows], [rows sampled], if the statistics out of date, or [rows sampled] far less than [rows], which many cause SQL Engine decided to use table scan instead of using your index.

Comment: I think the problem is the clause 'in the middle of a string/sentence'. As far as I know, there is no way of querying that using plain fulltext.